# Implementing a "load more" function

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently developing a personal php website. We have a page where different items are displayed ordered by score and date. Every user can "vote" each item (+1, -1). This page displays 10 items at a time and there is a "load more" button that gets the following items. Everytime the "load more" function is triggered, I run a query to get the next 10 items. To do this I run this kind of query

`SELECT *
FROM items
ORDER BY score DESC, date_added DESC
LIMIT '.$count.', 10`

Given the fact that users can increment/decrement the score of an item, it's possible that one same item could be queried the second time (on the "load more" trigger).

What could I do the fix this. I was thinking of a kind of snapshot of the table and getting saved data afterwards even if it would be old data.

Comment: If you click load more, you should be loading the next 10 items so you should not have duplicate items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save a list of already sent entrys (in a temporary table) and use

> WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM already_sent WHERE user_id = $uid)

This is a very quick and dirty solution, which does not scale very good on much requests, but I don't know a good solution, which would fit your needs. Another solution would be to prefetch your whole result and safe it for a specific set of requests, but this solution would probably limit your maximum results for a page (like 9gag does, for example)

Comment: I'd also go with `WHERE col NOT IN`. Maybe the performance can be boosted by not doing subselects, but fetching and passing the IDs that are going to be excluded manually.

Comment: But that would use a lot of bandwith between the webserver and MySQL when the lists are getting bigger with multiple requests. I think a MEMORY engine table on the server would be much more performant in that case. But I also can only say that this whole solution seems very ugly for me ;)

Comment: What does 9gag do when they reach their maximum on one page ?

Comment: @th3falc0n ^^^true that.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having an unpredictable table. I like the idea from @Thomas where you send the IDs already displayed and exclude those in the query. Another suggestion would be to always send 10-15 records and remove the duplicate ones (by ID) using javascript, for example.

Comment: Why is this table unpredictable? You reset it when user loads a page and then use it.

Comment: Because if you have lots of users accessing the page, it'll have an unpredictable growth (e.g. reddit hug of death). And how do you know when to reset the table? If you reset on every load, users will get duplicate items. If not, you'll have to keep it for a good amount of time in case users idle a lot and come back.

Comment: You can reload it when the user reloads the whole page, instead of just clicking "load more". But the unpredictable growth is a good aspect. But what could be a good way to implement something like this? The JS way is quite ugly too, because it has a chance to update not a single item, if all are already on client.